# Range error when loading coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a contact page that fetches the coordinates from localstorage

like  this

`localStorage.getItem("jc")`

I have used eval to convert string to variable

`var thecoords = eval(localStorage.getItem("jc"));`

and used the coordinates to center on those coordinates like

`var center = new google.maps.LatLng(thecoords);` and pan'ed to that location

`map.panTo(center);`

However i get this error

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I have checked my coordinates and they are in the right order of `lat,lng`

Why could i be getting this error?.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: What does the data in local storage look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google.maps.LatLng constructor takes two **Numbers** as an argument, not whatever you are passing it:

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(thecoords); // and pan'ed to that location
```

examples using [`google.maps.LatLngLiteral`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngLiteral) objects.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2v0mtbxa/1/)

**code snippet: (from jsfiddle, doesn't actually work due to sandboxing)**

```js
localStorage.setItem('jc', JSON.stringify({lat: 40.7127837, lng: -74.0059413}));
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('jc'));
    console.log()
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jc'))
    });
    map.panTo(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jc')));
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="clear" value="clear store" type="button" onclick="clearLocalStorage()" />
<div id="panel">
            <div id="color-palette"></div>
        </div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to use eval(). Items stored in local storage are already a variable. Don't use evil eval() at all.

Start off by console logging the coords and compare it to the Google Maps API docs.